# Shell Script compare the values with input parameter

Tags: shell

```
apps="http:git.abc.com";
cluster-ui="http:git.xyz.com";
customer-ui="http:git.xxx.com";
SERVICE=$1;
```

My requirement is if I pass service name as a 'apps' then I need to clone the $apps url.
Here

```
if [ $Service -eq apps ]
```

not think a good approach as my repo url might get increased so more and more loop will come
Any suggestions?

Comment: Not clear. Please do add more information for your question, also fix your samples correctly with CODE TAGS and let us know then.

Comment: You can't have `-` in variable name. The `-eq` is for comparing numbers, to compare strings use `=`. You mean you want to do `SERVICE=apps` and then `somemagic SERVICE` should output `http:git.abc.com`?

Answer (score 1):

The $ sign assigns the input argument, so we're getting first input if it matches the below variable, so do what you want inside if condition.

```
#!/bin/bash
apps="http:git.abc.com";
clusterui="http:git.xyz.com";
customerui="http:git.xxx.com";
#SERVICE=$1;

#Store global
repo=''

# if empty parameter is passed
if [ $# -lt 1 ] ; then
   echo "Parameters Need"
exit 1
fi;

# for search the correct parameter

if [ $1 = "apps" ]; then
   repo=$apps
elif [ $1 = "cluster-ui" ] ; then
  repo=$clusterui
elif [ $1 = "customer-ui" ] ; then
  repo=$customerui
else
   echo "Not found"
fi;

echo $repo
```

**Note** just repeat `elif [ ] ;then` for more entries or think!

***how to access*** run this file like this **`sh ./file.sh apps`** just replace apps with yours. make sure you have permission to execute the file if you don't have, give it to permission like below

`chmod 766 file`

now run the shell script `sh ./file.sh clusterui`

Comment: Yeah this one is good but not good if the repository to match is more. I think more efficient would be case statement.

Comment: case $SERVICE in  
app-lifecycle-ui) 
   repo=${appRepo}; 
      echo "Repository URL is" ${repo}; 
      ;;
healthcare-cluster-ui) 
      repo=${clusterRepo}; 
   echo "Repository URL is" ${repo};
      ;; 
   healthcare-customer-portal-ui)  
      repo=${customerPortalRepo}; 
      echo "Repository URL is" ${repo};
      ;; 
   *)
     echo 'Please drop an email to U49296@ust-global.com for adding your needed repository!' 
     ;; 
esac

Comment: I updated the above code so you can check it, add more variables with `elif []` condition to get the most out of this script. or study bash shell script or shell script to achieve what you want!

Comment: Thanks buddy! but elif will grow more if more to check. better go with 'case'.

Answer (score 0):

'Case statement' would suit here more than if ladder